# Systemd service with DynamicUser cannot write to its CacheDirectory

Tags: systemd, file-permissions, opensuse, systemd-service

I'm running OpenSuse Leap 15.4.

I have created a unit file for the [bazel-remote](https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote) remote cache server, for the Bazel build system.

I wanted to use the `DynamicUser` feature to make the service more secure, and avoid having to manually create a user for the service. I set the following parameters in the `[Service]` section of the file:

```
DynamicUser=yes
CacheDirectory=bazel-remote
```

Then, on the `ExecStart`, I passed the path `/var/cache/bazel-remote` to the bazel-remote binary.

**The problem** is that the `bazel-remote` binary is running into **permission errors** when trying to write to the folder. It successfully creates the directory structure inside the folder, such as:
`/var/cache/bazel-remote/cas.v2/00`, but it **fails when trying to create a file inside**.

I have verified the owner user and group of the entire folder structure matches the UID of the dynamic user running `bazel-remote`, and the permissions are set to `755`, so I don't understand why it cannot write a file there.

I have modified my unit file to use a fixed user and group, and it works without issues, so the problem is not the `bazel-remote` binary itself. But I would like to use the `DynamicUser` feature.

What could be going on? How can I solve the permission error?

Comment: Just an idea, try to change permissions to 775. Also please provide the error log. Another question, do you have enough free space left?

Comment: @paladin free space should not be the problem, as everything works fine with a fixed user and group. Wouldn’t manually changing the permissions in the autogenerated directory defeat the point?

Comment: @paladin I will try to provide the (heavily redacted) error log, although it doesn’t say much more than it cannot access the path.